# Error with MySQL insert query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
insert into sws(grade) values(100) where student_id='$session_id' & cys='$get_id2'
```

It shows error as

> You have an error in your sql syntax; check manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for right syntax to use near 'WHERE student_id='21' & cys='java' at line 1

Comment: have u tried `AND` instead of `&` ?

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message?

Comment: mkey's answer below will solve your issue. Once you've got this working you can click the tick next to his answer to accept it as the correct solution. Also then would be a good time to Google and research a bit more about MySQL Syntax. Welcome to Stack Overflow `:-)`

Comment: @Pred what makes you think that would solve the problem!?! I think reading error messages is an unusual problem solving trait that hasn't really caught on `:-D`

Comment: @Martin Well, since the question is off-topic, there was no intent to solve it. See [help/dont-ask] for more info. And yes, it helps a lot. The root cause of the syntax errors is a user error/typo/lack of basic knowledge of the language in almost all cases.

Comment: @Pred pssst, I was being just a little bit sarcastic! So many questions on SO come from folks not having error reporting or not *reading* their error reports. `:)`

Comment: @Martin we are off-topic too :) However I would say, it is mostly the second one (not reading) or pure laziness.

Comment: @Pred I often wonder if people have a social wide complex that error reports are somehow harder to understand simply by reputation. A file full of errors and a poor developer will be "ahhhh panic!" rather than seeing what the errors actually say... But I hope that's just my biased and unfair opinion.... Maybe errors should be renamed "Whoops" to make them loose the negative reputation (and connotations) and "I won't understand this"-perception, making people more approachable to solving them themselves. . . .

Comment: Ya i have tried AND instead of & but it shows same error. Please suggest me how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) Command *not* Insert

Replace the `&` with `AND` ([read about MySQL AND syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php)).

Answer (score 0):

INSERT syntax cannot have WHERE clause as you used, you might want to use UPDATE.

Basic UPDATE syntax :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

Comment: Insert statement is used when you want to insert a new record, but as per your query it seems that want to update a record based on a condition. So, as Javy said, use an UPDATE statement, instead of INSERT